# In Arduino, why create an intentional infinite loop?

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

In the [ASCII table example sketch](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ASCIITable) there is an intentional infinite loop:

```
  if (thisByte == 126) {    // you could also use if (thisByte == '~') {
// This loop loops forever and does nothing
while (true) {
  continue;
}
```

What is the point of doing this in `void main()`? Why not just put everything in `void setup()`?

Is this useful for running a function once? I think if it were to be used in a particular function, it would be stuck in the infinite loop.

Comment: They could have also surrounded the whole loop with `if (thisByte <126) { /* loop here */ }`.

Answer (score 1):

The infinite loop makes the Arduino stop doing anything in the `loop()` when a certain condition has been met. It is just a simple way to make it stop looping when it is done doing what it did. Putting the MCU in a deep sleep or power down mode indefinitely would also work for this.

And yes, you could do everything in `setup()`, that is always the case. Any Arduino program can be rewritten to do everything in `setup()`.

The main reason for not doing this is that `setup()` is intended for setting things up, and the `loop()` is intended for looping and running the main functionality, by convention, and because otherwise, the two functions would have silly names.

Everybody is free to do it their own way, though.